# How can I Merge two Lists of custom objects of a Different Type using Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have two *lists* of custom objects. And I want to merge both *lists* by `id`, using Java 8.

I have a class `Employee` with the fields (All String): `id`, `name`, `city`.

And I have another class `Person` with the fields (All String): `id`, `city`.

Here is an **example** :

```
   List<Employee> employeeList = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("100","Alex",""),
                        new Employee("200","Rida",""),
                        new Employee("300","Ganga",""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Person> personList = Stream.of(
                        new Person("100","Atlanta"),
                        new Person("300","Boston"),
                        new Person("400","Pleasanton"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After merging the two lists I want to get the result shown below.

How can I do it?

```
List<Employee> 
[
Employee(id=100, name=Alex, city=Atlanta), 
Employee(id=200, name=Rida, city=null), 
Employee(id=300, name=Ganga, city=Boston),
Employee(id=400, name=null, city=Pleasanton)
]
```

Comment: Don't forget to check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... actually you didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve that, firstly, you can create two ***maps*** based on the two lists using `id` as a *key*.

Then create a stream over the *key sets* of these maps. Then inside the `map()` operation you need to create a new `Employee` object for every key by using passing a `name` extracted from the `employeeList` `city` taken from the `personById` .

When `id` is not present in either of the *maps* the object returned by `get()` will be `null` and attempt to invoke method on it will triger the `NullPointerException`. In order to handle this situation, we can make use of **Null-object** pattern, by defining *two variables* that could be safely accessed and will be provided as an argument to `getOfDefault()`.

Then collect the stream element into a list with `Collectors.toList()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employeeList = Stream.of(
                    new Employee("100","Alex",""),
                    new Employee("200","Rida",""),
                    new Employee("300","Ganga",""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Person> personList = Stream.of(
                    new Person("100","Atlanta"),
                    new Person("300","Boston"),
                    new Person("400","Pleasanton"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<String, Employee> employeeById = employeeList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Function.identity()));

    Map<String, Person> personById = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity()));

    Person nullPerson = new Person("", null);             // null-object
    Employee nullEmployee = new Employee("", null, null); // null-object

    List<Employee> result = Stream.concat(employeeById.keySet().stream(),
                                          personById.keySet().stream())
            .distinct() // eliminating duplicated keys
            .map(key -> new Employee(key,
                    employeeById.getOrDefault(key, nullEmployee).getName(),
                    personById.getOrDefault(key, nullPerson).getCity()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output**

```
Employee{id='100', name='Alex', city='Atlanta'}
Employee{id='200', name='Rida', city='null'}
Employee{id='300', name='Ganga', city='Boston'}
Employee{id='400', name='null', city='Pleasanton'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Employee class here extends Person. Ideally, it should.

An Employee can be a Person, but not all Person has to be an Employee. So, collecting it as a `List<Employee>` makes no sense, due to this.

Ideally, you should collect it as a `List<Person>` and Employee should extend Person. Please relook at your class structure instead of focusing on collecting it as `List<Employee>`, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can use mapping and grouping from stream or search the second list by id and update the employee to the first list. Java does not include built-in functions that will automatically merge different objects